# Delete a line by relative line number

Tags: deletion, kill-text

I'm looking for solutions/suggestions on how to delete a line not under cursor but by relative line number. For example, how to delete the line which is 5 lines after the cursor without going to it in a first place.

Emacs/Spacemacs/Evil solutions are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple function and keybinding to `C-c d` will ask you for a number and will delete line that number forward (or backward if you will use negative number):

```
(defun kill-line-relative (&optional arg)
  "Kill relative line."
  (interactive "n")
  (save-excursion
    (forward-visible-line arg)
    (kill-whole-line)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c d") 'kill-line-relative)
```

You can play with `interactive` function parameters to use universal argument instead of explicit number request in minibuffer.